# How to Call in stored procedure another procedure with if statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have table **users** with vallues :

```
FirstName     LastName     Age
 A               A          20
 B               B          21
 C               C          22
 D               D          21
 E               E          20
```

then I create procedure ,where want check **Age** then in if statement call another procedures

```
SELECT @firstName = FirstName ,lastName = LastName ,@age = Age FROM dbo.users
if @age = 20
exec myProc1 'firstName','LastName'
if @age = 21
exec myProc2 'firstName','LastName'
if @age = 22
exec myProc3 'firstName','LastName'
```

When I call this procedure if statement take only one row and then call another procedure which is in IF statements,for example works only

```
   if @age = 20
    exec myProc1 'firstName','LastName'
```

because **Age = 20** is the first row in table. I want check all rows in table ,how do it ? Is it possible to do it without cursor ?

Comment: Did your previous question helped you. Both looks like sisters

Comment: What does your second stored procedure do? Perhaps it can be changed to be a table-valued-function?

Comment: All procedures send mails to different people

Comment: @GeoVIP I missed the line `without a cursor`. Deleted the answer, Sorry...

Comment: @GeoVIP: Just droped a answer, please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Side note: It's almost always a better idea to store a date of birth instead of Age (if you must have Age, make it a computed column from DOB). Otherwise, your data can easily fall out of date and you don't even know if it's out of date.

Comment: @HarishBhatt I accepted answer which help me, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `table` variable:

```
DECLARE @List TABLE(Id int IDENTITY(1,1), FirstName nVarchar(Max), LastName nVarchar(Max), Age INT)
```

then insert all data with in `table` variable

```
INSERT INTO @List (FirstName,LastName,Age)(SELECT FirstName, LastName, Age FROM YourTable)

DECLARE @intNumberOfRecords int, @intRowCount int, @FirstName nVarchar(Max), @LastName nVarchar(Max), @Age int
SET @intNumberOfRecords = @@ROWCOUNT
SET @intRowCount = 1  

WHILE @intRowCount <= @intNumberOfRecords  
BEGIN 


select @FirstName = FirstName, @LastName = LastName, @Age = age
from YourTable Where Id = @intRowCount 
if @Age = 20
    exec myProc1 @firstname, @LastName;
if @Age = 21
    exec myProc2 @firstname, @LastName;
if @Age = 22
   exec myProc3 @firstname, @LastName;

SET @intRowCount = @intRowCount + 1;

END
```

User can Also use `CASE` statement here instead of  `if`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this without a cursor.  But it still uses looping.

```
declare @t table as (id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
                     FirstName varchar(255),
                     LastName varchar(255),
                     Age int
                    );

insert into @t(FirstName, LastName, Age)
    select FirstName, LastName, Age
    from dbo.users;

declare @maxi int = (select max(id) from @t);

declare @i = 0, @FirstName varchar(255), @LastName varchar(255), @Age int;

while @i <= maxi
begin
    select @FirstName = FirstName, @LastName = LastName, @Age = age
    from @t
    where id = @i;
    if @age = 20
        exec myProc1 @firstname, @LastName;
    if @age = 21
        exec myProc2 @firstname, @LastName;
    if @age = 22
       exec myProc3 @firstname, @LastName;

    set @i = @i + 1;
end;
```

A couple things.  First, you don't really need the temporary table.  It is convenient for getting the loop counter.  Second, I also assume you want the variables as arguments to the three stored procedures rather than constant strings.

Comment: thank you for answering, this loop will be faster then cursor with fast_forward ?

Comment: @GeoVIP . . . You would need to test it to find out.  Cursors have certain overhead.  My guess is that this might be slightly faster, but the difference would not amount to much.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what is the use of i. in where condition you write where i=@i; but i think it would be id=@i. your answer is quite good but i think the best way to do this task is cursor.

Comment: @ABVyas . . . That was a typo.